# CollectionView with customCell layout doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, custom-cell

I am building an application using Xamarin.iOS. At first I want to display a list of categories in a GridView. For this I have used `CollectionView` with `Custom Cell Layout`. To build the Custom Cell Layout I have used "CollectioViewCell" from the interface which allows me to design the layout with Drag and Drop.

Below is the code:

**ViewController.cs**

```cs
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    //initialize the data
    sectionCategories = new List<SectionCategory>();
    sectionCategories.Add(new SectionCategory("Lajme", "LajmeUrl"));
    sectionCategories.Add(new SectionCategory("Lajme", "LajmeUrl"));
    sectionCategories.Add(new SectionCategory("Lajme", "LajmeUrl"));
    sectionCategories.Add(new SectionCategory("Lajme", "LajmeUrl"));
    sectionCategories.Add(new SectionCategory("Lajme", "LajmeUrl"));
    sectionCategories.Add(new SectionCategory("Lajme", "LajmeUrl"));
    sectionCategories.Add(new SectionCategory("Lajme", "LajmeUrl"));
    sectionCategories.Add(new SectionCategory("Lajme", "LajmeUrl"));

    sectionGrid.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(SectionViewCell), SectionViewCell.Key);
    sectionGrid.Source = new SectionViewSource (sectionCategories);
}
```

**SectionViewCell.cs**

```cs
public partial class SectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("SectionViewCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;

    static SectionViewCell ()
    {
        Nib = UINib.FromName ("SectionViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    }

    public SectionViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)

    {

    }

    public void UpdateCell (string text)
    {
        imageUrl.Text = text;
        sectionName.Text = text;
    }
}
```

**SectionViewCell.designer.cs**

```cs
[Register ("SectionViewCell")]
partial class SectionViewCell
{
    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UILabel imageUrl { get; set; }

    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UILabel sectionName { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
    {
        if (imageUrl != null) {
            imageUrl.Dispose ();
            imageUrl = null;
        }
        if (sectionName != null) {
            sectionName.Dispose ();
            sectionName = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**SectionViewSource.cs**

```cs
public class SectionViewSource: UICollectionViewSource
{
    public List<SectionCategory> category { get; set; }

    public SectionViewSource(List<SectionCategory> _category)
    {
        category = _category;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections (UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint GetItemsCount (UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return category.Count;
    }


    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        var cell = (SectionViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (SectionViewCell.Key, indexPath);

        cell.UpdateCell ("lajme");

        return cell;
    }
}
```

But when I run the app it throws me an error:

```cs
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MyIkub.SectionViewCell.UpdateCell (System.String text) [0x00008] in /Users/crs/Projects/MyIkub/MyIkub/SectionViewCell.cs:26
  at MyIkub.SectionViewSource.GetCell (UIKit.UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00019] in /Users/crs/Projects/MyIkub/MyIkub/SectionViewSource.cs:33
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2761/d7cac503/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:77
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2761/d7cac503/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:60
  at MyIkub.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/crs/Projects/MyIkub/MyIkub/Main.cs:12
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is at SectionViewCell.cs:26? either imageUrl, sectionName or the text seems to be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RegisterNibForCell` instead of `RegisterClassForCell`.

```cs
sectionGrid.RegisterNibForCell (UINib.FromName("SectionViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle), SectionViewCell.Key);
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://mikebluestein.com/2014/02/06/creating-collection-view-cells-from-a-xib/)

Comment: Saved my butt! Do you have any clue what that is? Xamarin's documentation and examples uses RegisterClassForCell. Do you think it's a bug?

Comment: Never mind! I found this article that explains why... wish that was more obvious lol